# How to change the vlookup function in excel into python script as the picture shown?

Tags: python, excel, robotframework, vlookup

I want to turn the vlookup function into python script, but i don't really know how to make it. The attached picture will be the vlookup funciton that I applied in the excel application. The lookup_value will be the column name 'HS code on declaration' from excel A, while the table_array will be the column A to B from excel B. Can someone help me to figure out how to turn this into python script?
[image]

And the vlookup function will be applied at the column HS CODE 2017:
[image]

After applied the vlookup, the value under HS CODE 2017 will be:
[image]

And here is the screenshot of excel B where the table array will be selected from column A to B:
[image]

Comment: does your table have any header?

Comment: how is this even possible ? you will need more parameters to it,for example , excel filename, its location ,et ctera? give full details of whta do you want to acheive

Comment: @Lutz yes my table has header name

Comment: @NikhilS Hi, the first excel path will be done.xlsx, while the second will be CORRELATION TABLE_EXCEL_HS 2022-2017.xlsx, lookup value getting from excel A, table_array getting from excel b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
import pandas as pd

def vlookup(excel_a_path, excel_b_path):
# Load Excel files into pandas dataframes
df_a = pd.read_excel(excel_a_path)
df_b = pd.read_excel(excel_b_path)

# Define the columns for lookup
lookup_column = 'HS code on declaration'
table_array_columns = ['PDK2022', 'PDK2017']
range_lookup = False  # Use exact match, equivalent to 0 in Excel

# Perform VLOOKUP
result_df = pd.merge(df_a[[lookup_column]], df_b[table_array_columns], how='left', left_on=lookup_column, right_on=table_array_columns[0])

# Extract the result column as a list
result_column = result_df[table_array_columns[1]].tolist()

return result_column

# Example usage:
excel_a_path = 'path_to_excel_A.xlsx'
excel_b_path = 'path_to_excel_B.xlsx'
result_list = vlookup(excel_a_path, excel_b_path)
print(result_list)
```

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?

Comment: ohh I didn't know this policy, cuz rarely use stackoverflow, will avoid it next time. Thanks for reminding me!